# question about convergence of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$X_n,X$ are square integrable random variables.We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E|X_n-X|^2=0$$
The question is can we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb EX_n^2=\mathbb EX^2$$

I use the Schwarz inequality, but I can't use the dominated convergence theorem because there is no function dominating $|X_n+X|$.(they are not necessarily bounded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the dominated convergence theorem. You just need to know that $\|X\|_2 = \sqrt{E[X^2]}$ is a (semi)norm in the space of square-integrable random variables. More specifically, the reversed triangle inequality holds:

$$|\thinspace \|X_n\|_2 - \|X\|_2\thinspace| \le \| X_n - X\|_2$$

The assertion now follows from observing that the maps $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ are continuous.

Comment: Excuse me , but I have a new question that can't avoid DCT : Does convergence in $L^2$ ($\mathbb E|X_n-X|^2\to 0$) imply square convergence in $L^1$ ($\mathbb E|X_n^2-X^2|\to 0$) ?

Comment: Yes, apply the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality to $|X_n^2 - X^2| = |X_n - X| \cdot |X_n + X|$.

Comment: but $\mathbb E|X_n+X|^2$ is not bounded by a constant $C$ , it is merely finite for each $n$

Comment: No, it is actually bounded.

Comment: Oh,I got an idea, since $\mathbb E|X_n+X|^2\le 2\mathbb E|X_n^2|+2\mathbb E|X|^2$, the former is bounded because it converges to the latter.right?

Comment: That is correct.